# wxSVG - problems with installation on linux

Tags: c++, svg, wxwidgets

So I have a problem. I would like to use wxSVG lib. I downloaded package from their website, however I dunno what should I do to make it work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That question should be asked on Super User.

Comment: Alternatively, you should at least try to explain what did you try to do and why did it fail.